# How to prevent multiple webpart instances after feature re-activation?

Tags: 2010, web-part, feature, custom, feature-activation

Every time I'm activating the feature that contains my webpart, a new webpart instance is added to the page layout. Do I want to this web part being replaced by its new version? What is the parameter that I have to set to prevent this behavior?

I read that 'replaceContent="true"' do the trick on SP2013 but what about SP2010?

Answer (score 0):

If you update your *.wsp which has the feature with powershell (Update-SPSolution) it will upgrade your solution already. 
If you are changing just *.cs code in your project, you can just compile the project and update the *.dll with gacutil command, and then recycling your application pool (to notice the dll)